# How do you fade in/fade out same div onclick of image using JQuery?

Tags: jquery

I want to fade in div onclick of image. I then want to fade out SAME div onclick of image again. Not sure how to go about it. The image and div are separate.

My code can be viewed on [JS Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ymubb3ez/).

```
  $(document).ready(function() {
    $("div#img1").click(function() {
      $("div#description1").fadeIn('slow', someFunction);
      });
    });


    function someFunction() {
      $("div#img1").click(function() {
      $("div#description1").fadeOut('slow');
    });
```

Comment: Check out `fadeToggle()` http://api.jquery.com/fadetoggle/

Comment: Ah, thank you!! It's a lot easier than I thought!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try

```
$("div#img1").click(function() {

         $("div#description1").fadeToggle('slow');

      });
 });
```